# Add footer or header to pdf when converting/printing from MS Word

Tags: 2013, word, pdf, printing

Is it possible to add some template text as footer or header when user wants to print word to pdf in SharePoint?
So on conversion from word to pdf we would like to add some text to footer.

Is this even possible? Any suggestion?

Comment: Unless you want to do a lot of custom programming, there is nothing in the out-of-the-box version of SharePoint that can do this. However, there are 3rd party options available to add watermarks to PDFs in SharePoint. Have a look at this Knowledge Base Article: https://support.muhimbi.com/hc/en-us/articles/228089247-Where-can-I-find-details-about-watermarking-. Disclaimer, I worked on this product so consider me biased.